# Problems installing rjags and JAGS on Mac OsX 10.5.8

Tags: r, installation, package

I am having issues getting rjags the R package for R to call JAGS (Just Another Gibbs Sampler http://www-ice.iarc.fr/~martyn/software/jags/ ).

I am running Mac Os X. 10.5.8 Leopard and using R64 2.12.1.  I compiled JAGS from the command line.   Then I installed rjags in the R command line.

> install.packages(rjags)

When I try to call rjags within R, I  get the following error.

```
> library(rjags)
  Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.12/Resources   /library/rjags/libs/x86_64/rjags.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.12/Resources/library/rjags/libs/x86_64/rjags.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjags.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.12/Resources/library/rjags/libs/x86_64/rjags.so
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
  /usr/local/lib/libjags.2.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
  /usr/local/lib/libjags.2.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
  Error: package/namespace load failed for 'rjags'
```

I am guessing there is some issue with rjags referencing an unknown file in the library, but I am not sure.  I am a fairly novice at the command line and messing around with directories, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found (after downloading and installing the dmg from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/)) that the following commands worked for me:

```
wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rjags_2.2.0-4.tar.gz
wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/R2jags_0.02-15.tar.gz
sudo R --with-jags-modules=/usr/local/lib/JAGS/modules-2.2.0 CMD INSTALL rjags_2.2.0-4.tar.gz
sudo R --with-jags-modules=/usr/local/lib/JAGS/modules-2.2.0 CMD INSTALL R2jags_0.02-15.tar.gz
sudo R --with-jags-modules=/usr/local/lib/JAGS/modules-2.2.0 --arch=i386 CMD INSTALL rjags_2.2.0-4.tar.gz
sudo R --with-jags-modules=/usr/local/lib/JAGS/modules-2.2.0 --arch=x86_64 CMD INSTALL rjags_2.2.0-4.tar.gz
```

They certainly aren't all necessary, but they were sufficient!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while running Rstudio 0.97.237 and R 2.15.2. The issue had something to do with JAGS.

The fix: Update to JAGS 3-3 by downloading and installing it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so': on my Mac and DuckDuckGo led me to this post. I was using R from the command line, so I can't speak to how it works with RStudio although I'm pretty sure it's the fix for that too. I updated JAGS from [the SourceForge link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/) provided in another answer. I can at least verify that it worked for me, though the developer was unsigned (I needed to ignore a MacOS warning during the installation procedure).